# Trying to create a moving sprite on a scrolling background

Tags: java, android

I got interested on Android, I'm new at it so I created a scrolling background and I want to put a sprite on it I already created a character class and the scroll background. I want to make the sprite move to the right but I'm getting error on my GamePanel.

The error is Non-static method(android.graphics.Canvas) cannot be referenced from a static context, what does it mean and How am I going to fix this and my make the sprite look like running to the right?

Here's my code:

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

public static final int WIDTH = 856;
public static final int HEIGHT = 480;
public static int Score =0;
public static int Highscore;
private MainThread thread;
private Background bg;
private Bitmap bmp;

public GamePanel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
    setFocusable(true);

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry) {
        try {
            thread.setRunning(false);
            thread.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            retry = false;
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    bg = new Background(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.gamebg));
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.deer);
    bg.setVector(-5);
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
public void update() {
    Score += 2;
    if (Score > Highscore) {
        Highscore = Score;
    }
    bg.update();
}
@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    final float scaleFactorX = (float)getWidth()/WIDTH;
    final float scaleFactorY = (float)getHeight()/HEIGHT;
    if(canvas !=null) {
        final int savedState = canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
        bg.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);

        Paint textpaint = new Paint();
        textpaint.setTextSize(30);
        canvas.drawText("Score:" +String.valueOf(Score), 0, 32, textpaint);
        canvas.drawText("High Score: "+String.valueOf(Highscore), 0, 64, textpaint);

    }
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Character.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access non static methods from a static context. So if you want to access a function or an object of the GamePanel class, you need to call this member by using the object instance of GamePanel class.

Just an example:

**wrong:**

```
GamePanel.draw(canvas);
```

**correct:**

```
GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel(this);
gamePanel.draw(canvas);
```